# How to compare month in spring mongo criteria of a column attribute

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mongodb-query

How can I compare month in spring mongo criteria with a hard corded value, month in criteria is in a spring format and the value is present in an integer format.

This is what i have so far i just want to check for that month and group employee ID if registrationDate repets

```
public List<Employees> getEmployees(){
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("registrationDate").is("2"));
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, Visit.class);
    }
```

but this returns empty which is not true because I have employees registered on february
and registration month in database is stored in this format "2023-02-06 00:00:00.000000"

Any suggestion will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a query like [this one](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pJDCaxhCv2D) so you can try something like this:

```java
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("date").month().equalTo(2)));
return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "collection", Visit.class).getMappedResults();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare the whole date, with the value of the month, which won't match, hence you get 0 results. If you have stored date values as strings, you can use `$regex`, like this:

```
public List<Employees> getEmployees(){
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("registrationDate").regex("^\\d{4}-02-\\d{2}"));
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, Visit.class);
}
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lg7eg3aa5sb)